# Difference between marionette events

Tags: events, marionette

I am reading the marionette.js docs and I don't understand the difference between `vent`, `reqres` and `commands`.

The only thing I clearly understood is that commands should not return anything.

Can anyone explain it a little bit?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's start from the top: [Backbone.wreqr](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr) is a Backbone plugin that ships with Marionette. It provides three messaging patterns for loosely-coupled applications.

This answer includes example code from the [Backbone.wreqr](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr) documentation - credit to the [original authors](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr/commits/master/readme.md).

### Events

`EventAggregator` objects work like `Backbone.Events` - they enable namespaced event handing. `vent` is simply a common variable name for an `EventAggregator` object:

```
var vent = new Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator();

vent.on("foo", function(){
  console.log("foo event");
});

vent.trigger("foo");
```

### Commands

Commands are very similar to Events. The difference is semantic - an event *informs* other parts of the application that something has happened. A command *instructs* another part of the application to do something.

```
var commands = new Backbone.Wreqr.Commands();

commands.setHandler("foo", function(){
  console.log("the foo command was executed");
});

commands.execute("foo");
```

### Request/Response

`RequestResponse` objects, which are often referenced by a variable called `reqres`, provide a loosely-coupled way for application components to request access to objects:

```
var reqres = new Backbone.Wreqr.RequestResponse();

reqres.setHandler("foo", function(){
  return "foo requested. this is the response";
});

var result = reqres.request("foo");
console.log(result);
```

### Radio and Channels

As a convenience, Wreqr provides an object called `radio` which mixes in the three messaging patterns. Commands, events and requests can be grouped into logical channels to prevent interference - you may need distinct `save` commands for `user` and `document` channels, for example.

### In Marionette

`Marionette.Application` creates instances of `Commands`, `RequestResponse` and `EventAggregator` inside a channel (`"global" by default)` using the conventional variable names. If you need custom behaviour you can override the `vent`, `commands` and `reqres` variables.

```
_initChannel: function() {
      this.channelName = _.result(this, 'channelName') || 'global';
      this.channel = _.result(this, 'channel') || Backbone.Wreqr.radio.channel(this.channelName);
      this.vent = _.result(this, 'vent') || this.channel.vent;
      this.commands = _.result(this, 'commands') || this.channel.commands;
      this.reqres = _.result(this, 'reqres') || this.channel.reqres;
    },
```

[Link to source](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette#section-413)

I suggest you read the [Wreqr docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr) for more detail. I also recommend reading through the [Marionette annotated source](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette) - it is concise and very well documented and, in fact, includes the Wreqr source.

N.B. The next major release of Marionnette, v3.x, replaces Wreqr with [Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio). Radio provides the same functionality as Wreqr with a cleaner API. It is possible to [use Radio in Marionette 2.x applications](https://gist.github.com/jmeas/7992474cdb1c5672d88b), which I recommend if you are starting a new app.

Comment: Very thorough and informative! Kudos for including the `Radio` upgrade in Marionette v3.0

Answer (score 4):

#### `ReqRes` Messenger

The `reqres` messenger can both send a message, (which consists of  the named `event` as well as optional parameters), to a target and relay a response back to the source (which will be in the form of the returned parameter of the target function)

#### `Command` Messenger

The `command` and `vent` messengers are functionally very similar, but fulfill different semantic responsibilities.

The `command` messenger is used to invoke the execution of a target function. Generally, one function is bound to a `command` handler. Like the OP stated, in a `command` the direction of communication is one-way, meaning that whatever the `command` target returns will not be sent back to the source incoming the `command`.

#### `VENT` Messenger

Finally, `vent` messengers are event aggregators. You can attach (subscribe) many listeners to the `vent` and all of them will receive an event that is triggered (published) by the `vent`. Each listener will invoke a function associated with that listener  When an event in a `ven`t is triggered it may also send each listener a set of parameters.